# Invalid Argument IE 8 jQuery

Tags: jquery, flash, object

I have this particular script that runs so that the flash elements don't show up on top of my slide out navigation. This redraws that flash element with wmode as opaque and so it shows up under the navigation. Works perfectly with Chrome and FireFox but not with IE. In IE I get an Invalid Argument in jquery.min.js code 0 Line 103 char 460. Can anyone help me as to why? If I comment out the second line of code inside the function then there is no error, but then doesn't work in FireFox. Any help is appriciated.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('embed').attr('wmode','opaque');
    $('object').append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque">');
    $('object').wrap('<div>');
   });
```

Comment: Just curious, still erroring if you close the tag, like this? `$('object').append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. This is what I did.

```
if ( !$.support.htmlSerialize ) { /*If browser doesn't support htmlSerialize then use altHtml embed here */
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).attr('altHtml'));
});
```

Comment: For me this changes the error to `SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'createDocumentFragment'` :-(